# I need to know how to get sound in Linux to do something specific

Tags: linux, alsa, alsamixer

What I want is to separate two different applications' sound output from each other, and pipe that into a sound editing program.

What I need is a way to add an entry in record that outputs into the playback tab. I need two of these.   I'm not sure if there are alsa (plumbing) commands to make these two connections, or phonon?

```
app1(output) > inputA --- outputA > editing app (input1)
app2(output) > inputB --- outputB > editing app (input2)
```

So I'll set the output device as the input device for the editing application. That will give me two separate audio sources in the same editing application.

Comment: It's very easy to do this with Pulseaudio (virtually all modern distros come with Pulseaudio on top of ALSA): Make a dummy sink, point editing app at monitor source of that sink (or even just use a hardware sink). So check if you have Pulseaudio installed. For ALSA only, you can use the loopback kernel module, but there some gotchas (no format conversion). If you can, use Pulseaudio (or Jack, as described in the answer).

Comment: I do have pulse audio. Can you give me the commands to do this? Will it work for two of them?

Comment: As a side note to help anyone else doing anything like this. If you want to push audio out of Chrome to anything other than your system output. You can use "AudioPick" on the Chrome store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Pulseaudio, and no null sink:

Start `pavucontrol`. Start all applications. Select `Output Devices`, look at which output device `app1` is using. Select `Input Devices`, set `input1` of `editing app` to the `.monitor` input of the output device you just saw.

This is inconvenient if you don't want to hear the sound `app1` produces, but only want to hear the sound of `editing app`. So create a null sink:

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=app1sink
```

Again in `pavucontrol`, set the output device for `app1` to `app1sink`, and set `input1` of `editing app` to `app1sink.monitor`.

You can do the same for `app2`, either with an additional `app2sink`, or using the same null sink. In the latter case the sound outputs of `app1` and `app2` will be mixed. You can adjust the volume for each add separately using `pavucontrol` (or the in-app volume control).

If `editing app` (which you didn't name) actually can't use two different ALSA/Pulseaudio inputs, and you are not content with the simple mixing of a single null sink as above, it gets a bit more complicated - in that case you have to decide **how** you want to mix `app1` and `app2` in Pulseaudio, so the single input for `editing app` does something useful.

Comment: This looks like it might work. I got the two monitors set up. I'll need to do some experimentation to see if this works. What is a null-sink? I assume it allows an input to play back to it's output? What makes this a null sink?

Comment: A null sink is a sound sink that goes nowhere (hence "null"). The associated `.monitor` input is a feature of *all* sinks, not the null sink in particular. So all sinks can "play back the output".

Answer (score 0):

[JACK](http://www.jackaudio.org/) can do such things.

If only some of your applications support JACK, you have to [route between JACK and ALSA](http://www.jackaudio.org/faq/routing_alsa.html).

If none of your applications support JACK, you might be able to use the `snd-aloop` driver to create virtual sound cards.

Comment: No, they don't sadly. I looked into this angle. That is why I went looking for an alsa angle. I'm not sure with the aloop method I can get two distinct inputs, and outputs in the sound mixer.

Comment: JACK seems amazing. I wish Linux embraced it more fully.